# Annotation of horizontal bar graphs in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to annotate horizontal bar graphs.
I am able to annotate vertical bar graphs using the example shown in matplotlib website but a similar idea for horizonatl doesn't seem to working.

The following is small working example for vertical

```
from pylab import *

ops = 90*rand(4)    # the bar lengths
pos = arange(4)+.5    # the bar centers on the y axis
rects1 = bar(pos, ops)

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')
autolabel(rects1)

show()
```

The following is the code I want to get working but doesn't work for horizontal graphs

```
from pylab import *

ops = 90*rand(4)    # the bar lengths
pos = arange(4)+.5   
rects1 = barh(pos, ops)

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        width = rect.get_width()
        plt.text(rect.get_y() - 1.05*rect.get_height()/2., 1.00*width,
                '%d' % int(width),
                ha='center', va='bottom')
autolabel(rects1)

show()
```

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        width = rect.get_width()
        plt.text(1.05*rect.get_width(), rect.get_y()+0.5*rect.get_height(),
                 '%d' % int(width),
                 ha='center', va='center')
```

[image]